# Problems with apache2 hierarchy

Tags: 14.04, apache2

I'm new to using Ubuntu, and specifically, the terminal. I've set-up a VPS to run Apache on.
Unfortunately, Apache seemed to already have been installed, so I used the command `apache2` to run it.
However, the installation was messed up, and the config file didn't exist among other files. I removed the `apache2` package, and reinstalled it, but found the same problem existed.
My question is, how can I completely reset the file hierarchy for Apache? It appears that removing it and installing it again doesn't work.
**UPDATE**
I have used `sudo apt-get purge apache2` and then `sudo apt-get install apache2`.
The command `apache2` is returning this:

```
[Sun Feb 08 00:44:30.834898 2015] [core:warn] [pid 11011] AH00111: Config variable ${APACHE_LOCK_DIR} is not defined  
[Sun Feb 08 00:44:30.834983 2015] [core:warn] [pid 11011] AH00111: Config variable ${APACHE_PID_FILE} is not defined  
[Sun Feb 08 00:44:30.834996 2015] [core:warn] [pid 11011] AH00111: Config variable ${APACHE_RUN_USER} is not defined  
[Sun Feb 08 00:44:30.835000 2015] [core:warn] [pid 11011] AH00111: Config variable ${APACHE_RUN_GROUP} is not defined  
[Sun Feb 08 00:44:30.835013 2015] [core:warn] [pid 11011] AH00111: Config variable ${APACHE_LOG_DIR} is not defined  
[Sun Feb 08 00:44:30.837863 2015] [core:warn] [pid 11011:tid 140685188798336] AH00111: Config variable ${APACHE_LOG_DIR} is not defined  
[Sun Feb 08 00:44:30.838044 2015] [core:warn] [pid 11011:tid 140685188798336] AH00111: Config variable ${APACHE_LOG_DIR} is not defined  
[Sun Feb 08 00:44:30.838052 2015] [core:warn] [pid 11011:tid 140685188798336] AH00111: Config variable ${APACHE_LOG_DIR} is not defined  
AH00526: Syntax error on line 74 of /etc/apache2/apache2.conf:  
Invalid Mutex directory in argument file:${APACHE_LOCK_DIR}
```

And the command `sudo service apache2 start` returns this:

`* Starting web server apache2`

Comment: Which file hierarchy? The `/etc/apache2` directory?

Comment: What was the output of the command `apache2`? Normally, you use the command `sudo service apache2 start` to start apache.

Comment: Did you try `sudo apt-get purge apache2`?

Comment: @douggro Yes, that's the one

Comment: The output for `sudo service apache2 start` means the apache server started correctly.

Answer (score 0):

I just installed Apache2 and these are the config files that were installed onto my computer.

https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/122705406/Google%20Drive/server%20default%20config/apach2e.zip

Download it, unzip it then replace the /etc/apache2 directory with this folder.

Also, start the apache server with

```
sudo service apache2 start
```

and you might want to try

```
sudo apt-get purge apache2
```

instead of `apt-get remove`.